# uiwebview webViewDidFinishLoad called before images show up

Tags: html, image, uiwebview

i have some local images in a local html file, which I am loading using `[webView loadHTMLString:htmlContent baseURL:baseURL];` . The page shows up, and a second later the images appear on it, which is undesirable. To fix this, I put a UIActivityIndicator in `webViewDidFinishLoad` . The UIActivityIndicator disappears after the text has been loaded, but the images still take a little while. The images are 4 KB pngs and I have some CSS and a table in my HTMLstring.

Comment: i have concluded that this is how image rendering is on uiwbviews. no solution